# В каком формате объект записываются в файл?

Tags: java, io

```
import java.io.*;

public class Collections {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try(ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("/home/arthur/Рабочий стол/text.txt")))
        {
            Person p = new Person("Sam", 33, 178, true);
            oos.writeObject(p);
        }
        catch(Exception ex){

            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        } 
    } 
}

class Person implements Serializable{

    private String name;
    private int age;
    private double height;
    private boolean married;

    Person(String n, int a, double h, boolean m){

        name=n;
        age=a;
        height=h;
        married=m;
    }

    String getName() {return name;}
    int getAge(){ return age;}
    double getHeight(){return height;}
    boolean getMarried(){return married;}
}
```

Вот информация записанная в файл
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как понять этот формат?

Comment: а что Вы тут хотите понять? как его обратно разобрать ?

Comment: а зачем прикладывать текстовую информацию картинкой? что бы людям сложнее было?

Comment: Объект записывается в виде байтов с определенной структурой. Структуру можно посмотреть здесь: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/serialization/spec/protocol.html